# Загрузка страницы с помощью PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

Есть сайт, который в браузере открывается спокойно.
При попытке открыть страницу с помощью PhantomJS - сайт возвращает код не страницы, а скрипта, выполнение которого, вероятно, должно привести меня на конечную страницу.

Но вот вопрос, почему PhantomeJS не выполняет этот самый скрипт и не переходит куда-либо?

Запрос элементарный:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://domain.com', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log('Content: ' + content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Ответ имеет вид, типа:

```
<html><head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05">
</script>
<script>
(function() {
var z="";var b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for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head></html>
```

Я понимаю, что это своеобразная "защита", но ведь это PhantomJS, вроде как эмуляция браузера, а не тупо парсер. Может мой запрос неверный? Нужно что-то ещё, чтобы скрипт выполнился на странице и показал конечный контент?

При входе на страницу с браузера - нет никаких перенаправлений, сразу открывается 200 ОК с содержимым страницы.

Comment: 1. Вы смотрели что за код находится в переменной b? 2. Он всегда один и тот же при получении страницы с помощью PhantomJS?

Comment: 1. А каким образом его можно посмотреть? Полагаю, он зашифрован и просто должен выполниться (для рядового пользователя).
2. Нет, код меняется.

Comment: Это коды букв, которые потом преобразуются в символы, а затем выполняются. Все эти действия описаны в самом скрипте.

Comment: Это понятно, но почему этот код не выполняется? Или он выполняется, но я не вижу какого-то ответа? Можно как-то понять, что возвращается при выполнении этого скрипта?

Comment: Да, вывести в консоль содержимое b, после вышеупомянутых преобразований.

Comment: В общем-то, понятнее ничего не стало. PhantomeJS воспринимается сайтом как робот и что с этим делать - непонятно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Google Chrome с недавних пор он умеет работать без интерфейса как Phantom.